# Date Regex with special character as optional pre element

Tags: javascript, regex, date, special-characters

Date Regex with special character as optional pre element

I need a date regex for YYYY-MM-DD, plus the following four case:

```
1978-12-20
>1978-12-20
>=1978-12-20
<1978-12-20
<=1978-12-20
```

How can I allow those 5 scenarios?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no attempt at writing code to implement the required logic.

Answer (score 1):

Imho, a regex is not the best tool for you, but if you still want to use a regex... a basic one, then you can use a regex like this:

```
^(?:>=?|<=?)?\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/nShWp5/2)**

Regex to match dates are kinda ugly. You can validate easily patterns, but dates have logic... for instance, not all months have 30 days, years are only 12 (should you count 01, 02, 03 or 1, 2, 3...).

Bear in mind that using above regex you will have invalid dates. So, you might want to capture the date string to ensure that it is valid first, and then apply this pattern to check if it is correct.

Comment: This is matching `=1234-12-12` but not wanted.

Comment: @PhilippM, I've updated the answer with more details, however in your question you didn't put almost any information. So, I came up with this basic regex.

Comment: @Toto, nice catch... thanks. Just fixed it.

Comment: I'm actually using https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#date but want to allow those additional four scenarios

Comment: @PhilippM, let me know if it works fine

Comment: What do you think about this regex? ^(?:>=?|<=?)?([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))

Comment: @PhilippM that's what I mean by "ugly". Your regex is correct... by imho hard to read, but if you are ok with it... go for it. In my personal case, I would go with my regex and validate that the date is correct with a regular date object.

Comment: Don't validate dates using a regular expression, it's way more complex than it needs to be. To test per the OP, `/^(>=?|<=?)?\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/` is sufficient. Then [validate the date](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+how+to+validate+a+date) separately.